# When can a girl marry after performing Head torch/Last rites

Tags: rituals

My question is,
When can a Kshatriya girl marry after performing last rites/head torch/Karmakand to her father? As she is the only daughter. she has to marry after 1 year or Can she marry after 6 months?
If married Can she do one year death anniversary rituals(pinda pradhan on 1 year death anniversary)to her father?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11782/3500).

Comment: After marriage, the son-in-law can do the rituals if he wants. There is a restriction if son does the rituals not to do any auspicious rituals for 1 year. But the daughter can marry within 1 year.

Comment: Sir,If daughter gets married in 1 year can she perform 1 year death anniversary rituals(pinda pradhan) to her father. People are saying that as she is marred she cant do rituals when her husband is there and husband can't do as his parents are there.