# Why suthak applies for different number of days in different casts?

Tags: tradition, caste-system, dharma-shastras

Why suthak effects on people for different days in defferent region or cast? I did read [THIS ANSWER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/death-in-family-does-a-marriage-need-to-be-postponed#answer-11782) and came to know about suthak. But from the answer and also from the comment section of this answer I came to know that Suthak apply for different number of days in different religion and cast! Why is that...?

First of all who decides days of suthak? Means, suthak will be applied for that many days, this is decided by whom? And why different days in different casts?

**UPDATE**

And also what will happen if we don't care about suthak and just follow our life's work by ignoring suthak's time?

Comment: I think this happened over time. Garuda Purana gives different times for different varnas (castes).

Comment: @TheDestroyer But why God believes in caste system (as you said Garuda Purana gives different times). I heard God sees all human as equal... was that a lie?

Comment: World can't work with same kind of people everywhere. Caste System is very complex theory. All Hindu Scriptures use word "Varna". They also say Varna is decided by Guna and Karma. Now, some people interpreted  Varna depends on birth (obviously with Guna and Karma) while some people say Varna depends on Guna  (and thereby Karma) only  and Varna can be changed in this very birth. You can check questions about [tag:caste-system] to know more details. World can only work with all kind of people. We need people who do work based on their Gunas and passions.