# Planning Bhoomi pooja after death of My father's elder brother

Tags: rituals, death

My Periyappa (My father's elder bother)died before one month.Thirty day rituals has completed.Now My family are planning do Bhoomi pooja. Shall we do this? Some people used to say, we have to wait for 3 months. Please suggest the good way.

Comment: This will be closed as you are asking for personal advice. So, what you have to do is frame the question in some manner without giving the personal stuffs.

Comment: Are you a girl or a boy? If you are a girl, are you married? If you are a married girl - your periappa's passing does not effect your /your husband's family's poojas.

Comment: I am a girl and i am not married. Shall we do it?

Comment: You can do it after 15 says or more depending on your caste and Region.

Comment: Related and could be duplicate too [Death in family - does a marriage need to be postponed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5248/3500)

Comment: It also depends on whether your father or any of your brothers performed the karma kaanDa. Please check with your purohita