# Death of a great grandmother from paternal side, and marriage of a great granddaughter (a female offspring)

Tags: marriage, dharma-shastras

[A question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/death-in-family-does-a-marriage-need-to-be-postponed) about death of a grandfather and postponement of granddaughter's marriage, [was answered with](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5249/):

> If there is a death on the paternal side, then all Subha karyas, including visit to kshetras, tirthas etc., except marriage of female offspring, need to be abandoned for a year i.e. till the samvatsara sraddha is performed. This is not "according to some people" but according to dharma. Such dharmas can be found in 1. Dharma Sindhu 2. Nirnaya Sindhu 3. Parasara Samhita 4. Varaha Purana 5. Anusasanika Parva of Mahabharata etc."

I am in a similar situation now. I would like to know if there are any special provisions regarding exceptional "provision of marriage of female offspring"

Is  there any verses which discuss about that special provision regarding "marriage of female offspring" in scriptures like Smrities ,Dharma Shastras etc.?